# WolframAlpha function that returns the 'decimal' part of a number

Tags: functions, decimal-expansion, wolfram-alpha, fractional-part

Is there a function or command in Wolfram Alpha for getting only the decimal part of a number?

Something like this: `DecimalPart(3.4231) = 0.4231`

I will be using this for calculations of very large numbers.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the *fractional part* function [`frac()`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=frac(pi)).

NB there are actually three different functions sometimes called the *fractional part*. All three agree at nonnegative real and negative integral arguments, but in general they differ for negative nonintegral arguments. Their implementations in W.A. are (along with suggestive examples):

- `frac(x)`: `frac(-1/3)` returns $-\tfrac{1}{3}$
- `x - floor(x)`: `(-1/3) - floor(-1/3)` returns $\tfrac{2}{3}$
- `abs(frac(x))`: `abs(frac(-1/3))` returns $\tfrac{1}{3}$

See the Wikipedia article [*Fractional part*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) for details.

Answer (score 5):

For positive numbers, you can always do $x-\text{floor}(x)$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/629048)

Comment: Uh? Try [$\pi-\text{floor}(\pi)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi-floor(pi)).

Comment: It could have been posted as a comment. Isn't it too short for an answer? Check the answer on the top.

Comment: It is not a comment; it is an answer. And what is the minimum accepted length for an answer?

Comment: I'm sorry if i reviewed it incorrectly. But I thought it would be better if it was a comment. (I just started reviewing).

Comment: No worries. I don't think it is a great answer, but it is an answer nonetheless. I personally find it detrimental to the site when people posts answers as comments (which unfortunately is very common).

Comment: @AdityaDev This answer seems correct and complete to me. That said, don't worry too much about "incorrect reviewing": There's a lot of room for subjective interpretation, and the system is self-correcting in that several users are polled for reviews before taking (non)action.

Answer (score 2):

This is called fractional part: $\text{frac}[x]$. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=frac(sqrt(2))) for an example.